# How to get the image of a transparent element without source?

Tags: jquery, html, background

I see an element in a HTML5 game which can be rotated, hidden and moved.
But it has a background... And the element is transparent.

For example, this moves the element:

```
$("#elementr2").animate({left: '650px'});
```

I can capture it perfectly because it is transparent.

What could I do?

Comment: You want to remove the background ?

Comment: yes is overlayed IM trying move the sprite in another place but all is backgrounded

Comment: I use screenshoot for capture but the image is diffuse because is backgrounded

Comment: If you printscreen to get the image, you always will have a background in the result. Can't you right-click it and "save image as..." ?

Comment: not exist this image its created for server cant extract only exist parts components but  not the complete image

Comment: This is a SVG ? [Wikipedia SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)

Comment: I think that if I could move this image to a part blank cant screentshoot perfectly but i can do this

Comment: I searched all html document and  dont get nothing

Comment: I have an idea for you... hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... If you can do this:

```
$("#elementr2").animate({left: '650px'});
```

Then, you can set a perfect white background covering the whole screen and bring only the wanted element above it.

```
// This will set a white background.
var myBackground = $("<div>").attr("style","width:100%;"+
                                   "height:100%;"+
                                   "top:0;"+
                                   "right:0;"+
                                   "bottom:0;"+
                                   "left:0;"+
                                   "background-color:#FFF;"+
                                   "position:fixed;"+
                                   "z-index:999999;"
                                  );

// This will bring the element you want above the background.
$("body").append(myBackground);
$("#elementr2").css({"position":"fixed",
                     "z-index":"1000000",
                    });
```

Comment: very thankyou , but fails  ;Luckily I found a white area where to locate my image thank you very much

Comment: I changed it... See if it works! Could be usefull for the next time.

Comment: very thankyou  I dont think that the problem Be your code
The server probably has a command that merges with the background

Comment: the result for use this command convert in white the background but also convert in white  the sprite

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to download the image asset?
You could check the network tab and find the resource there. It will probably be on its own or in a sprite sheet. Just filter the list by .png then right click on the asset, open in new window, right click, save as.

Comment: I check not exist this png is create for the server  I think that